# Swift type cast object to its specific class type?

Tags: swift

I am not sure if my title is worded correctly but here is what I am trying to do.

I have a general class called `Model` and I have classes which have extended this general class, namely, `Category`, `Tag`, `Author` etc.,

I have a method which accepts object of class Model, it can be Category, Tag etc.,

```
required init(entity: Model){
    self.entity = entity
    // here I want to call a Category/Tag/Author specific method.
    self.entity.isFollowed()
    // This throws error as isFollowed is only defined in 
    // Category/Tag/Author class and not in Model class.
}
```

**Question: How do I convert `entity` back to its actual object type ie., Category/Tag/Author?**

Comment: Do you ever use `Model` objects directly? If not, you should probably make it a Protocol: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Then you can define that all classes who implement the `Model` protocol should have a `func isFollowed()` method.

Comment: You should also have a read of the [type casting section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) of the language guide.

Comment: @Oskar I implemented the protocol approach. Had never used it before, comes in handy in these situations. Thanks!